# Replacement of sendDeepLinkData method in AppsFlyer Android version 6.6.1

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

sendDeepLinkData method is not found in AppFlyer version 6.6.1

I referred this document, I didn't find out the replacement method for sendDeepLinkData(activity)
https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001256006-AppsFlyer-Android-SDK-release-notes

This method removed from last AppFlyer version 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `sendDeepLinkData` method. The deep linking handling is done automatically by the SDK at the `onResume` state.

Comment: Hi Paz, it will be good if you give me the document link which has mention this kind of things

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Feel free to trust me regarding AppsFlyer SDK ;) anyway please see the v5.3.0 release note: "sendDeepLinkData method to get attribution data even if the user is deep linked into a specific activity has been deprecated in favor of the startTracking() method"

Comment: I think startTracking() is the replacement of sendDeepLinkData.

Comment: startTracking() (in v5) and start() (in v6) are simply statring the sdk and enable the functionally of the sdk (attribution, engagement and deep linking) . Once the SDK strated, it will fetch deep links automatically from the activity's intent. Please check the official deep linking documentation https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/android